# Browser shows 403 response when 401 is explicitly returned

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, apache2

I am using PHP's **http_response_code** to return various responses within my application.

However, sending a **401** response code results in my seeing a **403** response in my browser. Here is the relevant code:

**test.php**

```
<?php
    http_response_code(401);
?>
```

Here is the response:
[401 stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSrEe.png)

Other codes work as intended. Using:

```
<?php
    http_response_code(404);
?>
```

results in: [404 stated (censorship mine ofc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq9il.jpg)

Here is what I have attempted to far:

- Replaced http_response_code(401) with header("HTTP\1.0 401 Unauthorized")
- Grep'd every single Apache config file for ErrorDocument specifications for 401 (none)
- Added an .htaccess file in the same directory as **test.php** with the line "ErrorDocument 401 "I should see this on 401 responses"

Some more (maybe) relevant notes:

- I know 401 responses are typically used to request authentication (you're supposed to get that username and password field?)
- I am using it when authentication fails for a supplied username / API key combo
- I am also using http_response_code(403) later in the application *after* a user is authenticated, when they attempt to access a resource they don't have permissions for
- **Edit #1://** I have attempted this via CLI and cURL and received the headers "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.  )"
- **Edit #2://** Added `RewriteRule foo - [R=401]` to the `.htaccess` file in the document root - result was still a 403 when visiting `/foo`

My final question being - what haven't I checked so far that could result in this behaviour?

Comment: Check the actual HTTP response headers - make sure it's not just the browser's "friendly" error page that is "wrong". Looks like you are using IE? If you have "friendly error" messages enabled in IE then `ErrorDocument 401 "I should see this on 401 responses"` will never be seen.

Comment: @user82217 I have confirmed via cURL that the actual HTTP header I'm receiving is 403 (writing the headers to a file with the -D option). I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule foo - [R=401]` at the top of your `.htaccess` file and access the URL `/foo` - do you get a 401 response now? If yes then there is something in your application logic that is overriding your 401. If no, then something in the server config is overriding the 401 (although the `ErrorDocument` directive above kinda rules that one out?).

Comment: @user82217 Using `RewriteRule foo - [R=401]` results in a 403 response on `/foo`. I tried a couple of other codes and they still work as expected with that rule, just specifically not 401. I am coming to the conclusion that there must be some server config stuff I am unaware of, but I certainly feel as though I've searched everywhere.

Comment: "there must be some server config stuff I am unaware of" - it would seem so. The only time I've encountered a similar thing is when an overriding `ErrorDocument` is defined somewhere in the server config (that presumably changes the HTTP status) - although that shouldn't affect you when setting the HTTP status is PHP (the Apache `ErrorDocument` does not apply here). Are you testing this with just a minimal test file? No other directives in `.htaccess`? No other `.htaccess` files (anywhere along the filesystem path, including above the document root)?

Comment: "Added an .htaccess file in the same directory as test.php" - Is `test.php` not in the document root?

Comment: @user82217 `test.php` is **not** in the document root. There are other `.htaccess` files (including the document root), however this only contains an `ErrorDocument 503` line, and a couple `RewriteCond` for seeming unrelated tasks (something about a visualcron server). `test.php` is located within a subdirectory of the root. The test file is _exactly_ as described above. As mentioned, I have scoured the `/etc/apache2` directory for any conflicting rules and did not find anything that would seem to point to this happening.